# Displaying left and right navbar links on separate lines on collapse

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a question about positioning my links on navbar collapse. I want the left sided links to be displayed on one line in the collapsed menu, and the right sided links to be displayed on the next line.

Right now I can get all the links displayed on the same line using "display: inline-flex" in my css, but I don't know how to separate them.

Here is my current HTML and CSS:

```
<div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
          <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>

.navbar-right {
    float: right;
    margin-right: -15px;
}

.collapse > .navbar-left {
  display: inline-flex;
}

.collapse > .navbar-right {
  display: inline-flex;
}

.navbar .navbar-nav {
  float: none;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: center;
}
```

And a link to my jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wdeg6rko/

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a media query to contain the rules so they only apply under 768px and use inline-block against the `li` items and set the navbar-navs width to 100% while removing any margin so they are actually centered.

Working example Snippet.

```css
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .navbar.navbar-default .navbar-right > li,
  .navbar.navbar-default .navbar-left > li {
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 4</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 5</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As there is `float: left !important;` is added to `.navbar-left`. To override it use following css:

```
.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-left {
    float: none !important;
}
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wdeg6rko/1/)**